# javac コマンドを実行しても "ファイルが見つかりません: *.java" と表示されてしまう

Tags: java

昨日までは `javac` コマンドが使えていましたが、急に以下のメッセージが表示されるようになってしまいました。解決策募集します。

**表示されたメッセージ**

```
javac: ファイルが見つかりません: konp.java
使用方法: javac <options> <source files>
使用可能なオプションのリストについては、-helpを使用します
```

**konp.java**

```
public class konp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sales[];        // 宣言
    sales = new int[4]; // 領域の確保
    sales[0] = 150;
    sales[1] = 200;
    sales[2] = 140;
    sales[3] = 400;
    //sales.length;     // 領域の個数４

    for(int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(sales[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

**実行環境**
Windows 7 (64bit)

Comment: ファイル名をチェックしてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。直しました。ファイル名は合っています。
いまだエラーです。

Comment: 拡張子は`.java`ですか？ ディレクトリ階層はあっていますか？コマンドラインでの実行ですか？ 当該ファイルのあるディレクトリでコマンドプロンプトを起動して`javac konp.java` はできますか？ `javac k`の状態でtabキーを押してファイル名が補完されますか？ パッケージ指定はしてたりしますか？

Comment: コマンドプロンプトです　javac　konp.javaで上記のエラーでました

javac　k ってなんですか？　javacでいろいろ出てきます。


パッケージ指定がよくわかりませんが、してないとおもいます

Comment: なるほど、`javac` とファイル名の間を全角スペースで区切ったのですね。半角スペースで区切ってみて下さい(`javac konp.java`)。# とはいえ、それだとエラーメッセージと合わないな、、？

Comment: _javac　k ってなんですか？_ この場合、ファイルの中身ではなくファイルが存在するかどうかが問題ですのでファイルが存在することを確かめようとしています。プロンプトで`javac k`までタイプしたところでtabキーを押すとそのディレクトリでkで始まるファイル名のファイルが補完されて次々に表示されます。逆に言えばこの手順の中で`javac k` が補完されて`javac konp.java`にならないようならそのフォルダにそのファイルは存在しません。

Comment: 絶対パスで指定してみてはどうでしょうか。`javac C:\hoge\fuga\konp.java`。単にカレントディレクトリにファイルがないだけだと思います。

Comment: javac kをコマンドプロンプトでやってみましたが、エラー音がでて何も表示されません。。半角スペースで実行しています。

Comment: 絶対パスっていうのは
C:\Users\rqwqk\Documents\javayou\konp.java 
とかのことでしょうか？　　最初から絶対パスだったと思います。

Comment: C:\Users\rqwqk\Documents\javayou\konp.javaで実行すると内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド　略　になります

Comment: 「昨日まで使えていた」とありますが、同じように`javac konp.java`としていたのでしょうか？

Comment: _エラー音がでて何も表示されません_ そのディレクトリには所望のファイルがありません。

Comment: 例えば、`dir *.java`と実行して現在のカレントディレクトリ（コマンドプロンプトの起動しているワーキングディレクトリ）にファイルが存在することを確認して下さい。 おそらくカレントディレクトリが異なるということなので、エクスプローラーでファイルを確認したらそのフォルダで右クリックから「コマンドウインドウをここで開く」からコマンドプロンプトを表示してそこで実行するか`cd`コマンドでディレクトリをファイルが存在するディレクトリに移動します。例 `cd C:\Users\rqwqk\Documents\javayou`

Comment: 実際のファイルの名前が半角になっているか確認すると良いかもしれません。確認ついでに一回ファイル名をリネームしても良いと思います。今回は無関係かと思いますが、拡張子が非表示になってて実は`konp.java.txt`だったりする例もあるようです。

Comment: あと`javac C:\Users\rqwqk\Documents\javayou\*.java`を実行して同様のエラーが発生する場合、`C:\Users\rqwqk\Documents\javayou\ `配下にjavaファイルは存在しないかと思います。

Comment: dir konp.javaでC:\Users\rqwqk>dir konp.java
 ドライブ C のボリューム ラベルがありません。
 ボリューム シリアル番号は 2876-EB71 です

 C:\Users\rqwqk のディレクトリ　　とでました。。

javac C:\Users\rqwqk\Documents\javayou\*.java　を実行すると、
何も表示されませんでしたけど、コンパイルできてるということでしょうか。
しかし、java konp ではエラーが発生しました。

Comment: `cd Documents\javayou` してからコマンド実行してみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。。できました。。。。　しかし、なぜcd で移動しなければならなかったんでしょうか。。。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトが起動したディレクトリ（現在のワーキングディレクトリ）とjavaソースのあるディレクトリが異なったからですね。(絶対パスを指定しない場合ワーキングディレクトリ（カレントディレクトリ）でファイルを探すから）

Answer (score 3):

「ファイルが見つからない」系のエラー原因はいろいろありますが、最初に基本的な確認をするのが早道だと思います。

- 見つからないファイルのパス名が絶対パスのとき、絶対パスを指定して、そのファイルが存在するかをコマンドで確認する。
- 相対パスの場合は、エラーが発生したプログラムのワーキングディレクトリを調べ、そのディレクトリで、早退パスを指定して、そのファイルが存在するかをコマンドで確認する。
- パスがわからない場合はLinuxであればstrace等のシステムコールトレースを実行して、トレース結果からopenエラーが見つかればパスがわかることがあります。